# IndexedDb store reset with .clear(), but quota never decreases

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

I'm trying to use the IndexedDb database in Chrome for storing undo points (very big typed arrays of data).

Since undo info has a single session lifetime, I clear the store every time my app is initialized. Everything seem to work ok, but when I query the quota, it seems always peristently decreasing. I know that the store is cleared because, if I use a cursor, there are no more keys in it.

The only way to decrease the quota is to manually erase the database from the Settings menu.

Is clearing the store not enough to free the sources and re-set the quota? Here's what my code does at init:

```
        idxdDB.open = function () {
        var version = 1;
        var request = indexedDB.open("db_undo", version);

        // We can only create Object stores in a versionchange transaction.
        request.onupgradeneeded = function (e) {
            var db = e.target.result;

            // A versionchange transaction is started automatically.
            e.target.transaction.onerror = function (e) {
                console.log("Error", e);
            };

            if (db.objectStoreNames.contains("undo_point")) {
                db.deleteObjectStore("undo_point");
            }

            var store = db.createObjectStore("undo_point");
        };

        request.onsuccess = function (e) {
            idxdDB.db = e.target.result;

            // Clear the store
            var trans = idxdDB.db.transaction(["undo_point"], "readwrite");
            var store = trans.objectStore("undo_point");

            var req = store.clear();
            req.onsuccess = function(evt) {
                console.log("Store cleared");
                getQuota();
                listAllStore(store);
            };

        };

        request.onerror = function (e) {
            console.log("Error!", e);
        };
    };
```

And here's what I use to query the quota and list all the entries in the store:

```
function getQuota () {
      if (window.webkitStorageInfo && window.webkitStorageInfo.queryUsageAndQuota) {
        window.webkitStorageInfo.queryUsageAndQuota(webkitStorageInfo.TEMPORARY,
          function (used, remaining) {
              console.log("Used quota: " + used + ", remaining quota: " + remaining);
          }, function (e) {
              console.log('Error', e);
          });
      }
    }


function listAllStore (store) {
        store.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
            var cursor = event.target.result;
                // if there is still another cursor to go, keep runing this code
                if(cursor) {
                    console.log (cursor);

                    // continue on to the next item in the cursor
                    cursor.continue();

                    // if there are no more cursor items to iterate through, say so, and exit the function 
                } else {
                    console.log ("Cursor finished");
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `indexedDB.deleteDatabase('DB NAME')`

Comment: Works. I'm still confused about why clearing the database does not do the trick, though.